# Can these types of SPARQL queries be executed?

Tags: rdf, sparql, semantic-web, jena

Supposed we have a huge RDF graph and want to do the following: (I tried it and it doesn't work - wanted to know if I am constructing the query incorrectly or some issue with the rdf dump).

```
select ?n ?o 
where {
    ?n <name_of_a_node> <name_of_this_node>.
    ?n ?p ?o.
    ?o <type_of_a_node> ?t.
    FILTER(REGEX(STR(?t), "president")).
}
```

The above query says that I know the name of node n. So, I am getting the URI of node n. Then, I am fetching all the predicates of node n and other nodes connected visa this predicate. For each of these nodes o that are connected to node a, I want to look at their property (a type property) and retrieve only those nodes o that have a substring in their type property.

Is this possible in SPARQL? Basically, standing on a node and looking at all the other nodes that this node is connected to, and then retrieving only those nodes that match another condition on their properties.

Otherwise, should I just retrieve all nodes o that node n is connected to and for each of them, run another SPARQL query to do this check?

I am using JENA to store the data.

Comment: "I tried it and it doesn't work" doesn't tell anyone enough to help you. What were the symptoms of not working? Which predicates did you use for `name_of_a_node` etc? Basically, yes, the *structure* of your query is fine, but to help you get it working we need details.

Comment: Did you make any progress with this?  Also, note that SPARQL 1.1 supports `contains` which is likely to be more efficient than `regex`.

Answer (score 5):

Yes this is possible but writing a query like this is almost always very ill advised.

Any `FILTER` you use requires a SPARQL engine to look at every possible solution and evaluate the expression within it, while many expressions are quick and cheap to evaluate some like `REGEX` are very expensive.

Essentially you are asking the SPARQL engine to get some large unbounded swathe of possible results and then apply a regular expression against every possible solution.  If you know anything about [Java regex performance](http://tusker.org/regex/regex_benchmark.html) then you would know this is often a very bad idea irrespective of it's use in SPARQL.

Many SPARQL engines support [full text extensions](https://web.archive.org/web/20160814144717/http://answers.semanticweb.com:80/questions/8676/do-you-use-full-text-search-with-sparql-if-so-how-and-why) which allow you to express these kinds of queries in a way that lets a SPARQL engine process them much more efficiently.  For Apache Jena see [LARQ](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/larq/index.html)

Comment: http://stardog.com also supports full text search, and supports the same LARQ syntax that Jena provides.  AllegroGraph (http://www.franz.com/agraph), afaik supports some sort of full text search as well, but i'm not sure if it integrated into SPARQL query answering.  But you do have other options besides LARQ.